ub 24.04 X server fails to start , nouveau driver is loaded but no /dev/dir/card0 and no /dev/fb0
Hi  I've painted myself into a corner.  Unsatisfied with the nouveau driver I tried the software updates and to install nvidia-driver-390 but it fails.
So I am trying to got back to the nouveau driver.  So far no Luck.
https://pastebin.com/s8TFC1cR
/var/log/Xorg.0.log
 apt search nouveau
Sorting... Done
Full Text Search... Done
bumblebee/noble 3.2.1-29ubuntu3 amd64
  NVIDIA Optimus support for Linux

libdrm-nouveau2/noble,now 2.4.120-2build1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  Userspace interface to nouveau-specific kernel DRM services -- runtime

nouveau-firmware/noble,noble,now 20091212-0ubuntu2 all [installed]
  Firmware for nVidia graphics cards

xfonts-jmk/noble,noble 3.0-23 all
  Jim Knoble's character-cell fonts for X

xserver-xorg-video-nouveau/noble,now 1:1.0.17-2build1 amd64 [installed]

I've run
sudo apt purge nvidia-driver-390
sudo apt install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
sudo apt install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core
sudo apt install --reinstall nouveau-firmware
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
But it still boots to a blank screen.
Its not a lack of posts about this issue its more the volume of posts about this error.
any other info that would help just ask.
Edit1: just noticed that the gpu-manager.log and  gpu-manager-switch.log both show Is nouveau blacklisted? yes and the later shows
Error: can't access /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:05:00.0/driver
I've checked /etc/modprobe.d/ for and blacklisting of nouveau but found none. Any were else where blacklist is located? I am not finding anything about /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:05:00.0/driver
Edit2: lsmod doesn't list the nouveau driver.
/etc/modules-load.d/modules.conf 
# /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
#
# This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
# at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.

nouveau

# Generated by sensors-detect on Tue Dec  5 07:50:07 2023
# Chip drivers
adt7475
coretemp
nouvea

Thanks for looking
Jim

Turns out one of the attempts to load the nvidia driver installed a blacklist file:
/usr/lib/modprobe.d/nvidia-installer-disable-nouveau.conf
this was causing the gpu-manager.log to show "nouveau blacklist yes"

Once I commented out the values in that file the boot worked like normal.
Thanks
Jim
